# NSMutableDictionary not reading anything from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, cydia-substrate

I have a plist file at: /var/mobile
But it seems that my mobilesubtrate tweak does not read anything from the plist file.

This is my code:

```
   NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/test.plist";
   self.mods = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

`self.mods.count` returns 0, and the entire dictionary is empty.
The plist file does have 3 key/value pairs.

I found a crash report log on my phone, it said this

Sandbox Violation:   minecraftpe deny file-read-metadata /private/var/mobile/test.plist

I guess the tweak is still sandboxed and can't access files outside the app?

Comment: Does [Can't find /var/mobile/Applications directory for iOS documents](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9014406) help?

Comment: Don't see how that can help me. The problem is that, the file in my phone exists and I can access it, but my tweak can't read it for some reason

Comment: I would firstly make sure that the plist has valid formatting etc by doing a validation: open terminal ant type plutil <path to plist file> and see if you get any formatting errors.

Comment: You're trying both strictly on the device, not in the simulator?

Comment: @DanSpag No problem at all

Comment: @JoshCaswell On the device, not in the simulator

Comment: Return Value -- A new dictionary that contains the dictionary at path, **or nil if there is a file error or if the contents of the file are an invalid representation of a dictionary**.

Comment: I'd suggest you open the file with some operation that has an `error:` parameter, and see what is reported.

Comment: Is the plist root a dictionary? As you may know it could be either Dictionary or Array.

Comment: Simplest would probably be [NSString `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:).  You could NSLog the resulting NSString to observe the data actually read from the file.

Comment: @DanSpag The plist root is dictionary

Comment: @HotLicks I will try to do so tomorrow

Comment: (The encoding should generally be NSUTF8Encoding or whatever it's called.)

Comment: I found the problem, I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

AppStore apps are sandboxed. Tweaks are code that run within the process that the filter specifies.  Apps have a process in which the tweaks are injected, therefore they have the same limitations.

You can however read from `/User/Library/Preferences/com.your.tweak.preferences.plist` by using the NSUserDefaults class. If you need other types of files you could look into using sandcastle to escape the sandbox and get the files from elsewhere.